Why does the `Invoke-Expression` not support redirecting the error stream directly?
I'm a novice in PowerShell.
Recently, I encountered a problem about dealing with output streams. I've found that the Invoke-Expression cmdlet does not support redirecting the error stream directly.
Here are my tests:

First, the direct redirection of Invoke-Expression misses the Error stream:
# pwsh 
function Test-Log {
    Write-Debug "This is a Debug message" -Debug
    Write-Verbose "This is a Verbose message" -Verbose
    Write-Host "This is a Host message"
    Write-Output "This is an Output message"
    Write-Error "This is an Error message"
    Write-Warning "This is a Warning message"
    Write-Information "This is an Info message"
}
Invoke-Expression "Test-Log" *>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable output | Out-Null
Write-Host "===Begin of output==="
$output
Write-Host "===End of output==="

The output is:
===Begin of output===
DEBUG: This is a Debug message
VERBOSE: This is a Verbose message
This is a Host message
This is an Output message
WARNING: This is a Warning message
This is an Info message
===End of output===


Second, the redirection of a block that contains Invoke-Expression does not miss the Error stream:
# pwsh 
function Test-Log {
    Write-Debug "This is a Debug message" -Debug
    Write-Verbose "This is a Verbose message" -Verbose
    Write-Host "This is a Host message"
    Write-Output "This is an Output message"
    Write-Error "This is an Error message"
    Write-Warning "This is a Warning message"
    Write-Information "This is an Info message"
}
&{Invoke-Expression "Test-Log"} *>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable output | Out-Null
Write-Host "===Begin of output==="
$output
Write-Host "===End of output==="

The output is:
===Begin of output===
DEBUG: This is a Debug message
VERBOSE: This is a Verbose message
This is a Host message
This is an Output message
Test-Log: This is an Error message
WARNING: This is a Warning message
This is an Info message
===End of output===



I can understand the second scenario, as the Error stream will not disappear for no reason. But I don't understand the first one. It seems like the *>&1 used to redirect Invoke-Expression's output does not influence the Error stream within it.
I've found some official docs about Invoke-Expression, although they do not seem helpful:

Invoke-Expression
Avoid using Invoke-Expression

Thanks in advance.

I don't have an explanation, just another workaround: Invoke-Expression "Test-Log *>&1" | Tee-Object -Variable output | Out-Null
